# Access parent's property

Tags: javascript, oop

Hi I need to change the **mousemove** property onMouseMove but I can't access the **myfunc** object because **this** refer to the **el** not the parent !!

```
function myfunc (el) {
  this.el  = el;
  this.mousemove = false;

  el.onmousemove = function(){
      this.mousemove = true;
  };
}
```

Comment: The scope of `myfunc`. Let's find a duplicate.

Comment: Refer to `el` instead of `this`. Problem solved.

Comment: You probably don't exactly know how to use `this`. Let's refresh your knowledge: [MDN: `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just store a reference to `this`, call it whatever you'd like. It's common to use `that` or `self`:

```
function myfunc(el) {
  var that;
  that = this;
  this.el = el;
  this.mousemove = false;
  el.mousemove = function () {
    that.mousemove = true;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a reference to the relevant `this`; e.g.

```
function myfunc (el) {
  this.el  = el;
  this.mousemove = false;

  var t=this;
  el.onmousemove = function(){
      t.mousemove = true;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `this`'s because they all refer t `window`

```
function myfunc (el) {
  var mousemove = false; //scoped

  el.onmousemove = function(){
      mousemove = true; //same scoped variable
  };
}
```

Comment: not if myfunc was assigned to an object or prototype after it was declared.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the `mousemove` value from the `onmousemove` handler.  If so then you need to capture the original context in a value which you can later access.  For example

```
function myfunc (el) {
  this.el  = el;
  this.mousemove = false;
  var self = this;

  el.onmousemove = function(){
      self.mousemove = true;
  };
}
```